scroll to in react native
I'm looking for a method to scroll to a specific position when clicking a button in React. It's easy in React with scrollIntoView, but in React Native, nothing is simple and I can't find a method to do it :/ I tried with useRef and scrollTo on ScrollViews, but it doesn't work.
If anyone has any suggestions, I'm all ears.
 const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);
  const section3Ref = useRef(null);

  const scrollToSection = () => {
    if (scrollViewRef.current) {
      scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y: 200});
    }
  };
return( <Architecture ref={scrollViewRef}>
        <Button title="Scroll to Section 3" onPress={scrollToSection} />
        <View ref={section3Ref}>
        <VeterinarianPet />
        </View>
         </Architecture>
)

I would like that when I click on the button it scrolls to the veterinarian component
sorry in advance for my english
this is my component Architecture
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import {
  
  ScrollView,
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  Dimensions,
 
} from "react-native";
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view";
import tw from "../../tw-rn";

interface ArchitectureProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  ref?: any;
}

/**
 * Architecture component allows scrolling in the page - Composant Architecture permettant de scroller dans la page
 * @param {object} children - Children components - Composants enfants
 * @returns {JSX.Element} - Architecture component allows scrolling in the page - Composant Architecture permettant de scroller dans la page
 */
const Architecture = ({ children ,ref }: ArchitectureProps) => {
  const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");
  return (
    <View>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
          <ScrollView
            nestedScrollEnabled
           ref={ref}
          >
            <View style={tw`pb-25`}>{children}</View>
          </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Architecture;



shouldn't it be createRef()?

@injecteer No, it should be useRef()

Hello:)
The problem is with the Architecture component. It should be the ScrollView component for react-native. If you are using custom components please provide the code for the Architecture component.

hi thanks for answer :) , i add Architechture component

@AdamBasha i add Architechture component

Hello:)
I think this might help: https://www.upbeatcode.com/react/scroll-to-an-element-in-react/

scrollIntoView cannot be used in react native :/ . and scrollTo, does not work for me I have error: " ERROR  TypeError: myScroll.current?.scrollTo is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes"

i solved my problem !
const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);

  const scrollToPosition = (y) => {
    scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo({ y, animated: true });
  };

  return (
    
      <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef}>
        
        <Button title="Scroll to 500" onPress={() => scrollToPosition(800)} />
       
           
      </ScrollView>
      
  );
};

the problem was that I passed my ref in props in "Architechture". just change in scrollViews and it's good :)
thanks you for answer
